# How to still using NSS cache daemon in place of NSS LDAP cache daemon

Tags: debian, ldap, nss

I've Debian 7.11 as client of my LDAP. This morning after an update I 've got the surprise my debian doesn't want to connect to my LDAP anymore. It's seems the nslcd took the hand on nscd.

Anyway is it possible to restore back the old nss system ?

For taking front of the problem I tried to configuring my nslcd.conf like this :

```
uid nslcd
gid nslcd

uri ldap://server.acme.com
base dc=acme,dc=org
binddn cn=proxyuser,ou=pam,dc=acme,dc=org
bindpw clearpasswd

base    passwd  ou=People,dc=acme,dc=org
base    shadow  ou=People,dc=acme,dc=org
base    group   ou=Group,dc=acme,dc=org

pam_authz_search        (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=$username))
```

I've got the user and group checked with the command `gentent passwd`  but not the shadow as the su user doesn't work :

```
su - user1
No passwd entry for user 'user1'
```

I'm thinking the nsswitch.conf is configured well :

```
passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files ldap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that work for me :
I reconfigured the impacted package

```
# dpkg-reconfigure libnss-ldapd
# dpkg-reconfigure libpam-ldapd
# dpkg-reconfigure nslcd
```

That pops up this windows in my terminal the first step is to configure the /etc/nsswitch.conf :

[image]

Second give the URI of the LDAP server :

[image]

Third step give the distinguished name of the base :

[image]

Fourth step give the type of authentication for the LDAP Base:

[image]

Fifth step give the account for the authentication :

[image]

Sixth step give the password of the account :

[image]

Seventh give the encryption type :

[image]

After that the `getent password` show me all the login which are inside the LDAP Base

PS : Sorry for the french snaptshot